# None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied in jetpack compose Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

this problem occurred when trying to add `feature-section background` in jetpack compose

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
  public fun Modifier.background(brush: Brush, shape: Shape = ..., alpha: Float = ...): Modifier 
  defined in androidx.compose.foundation
  public fun Modifier.background(color: Color, shape: Shape = ...): Modifier
  defined in androidx.compose.foundation
```

You can also see the problem in this image :

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please do not post images of code.  Instead, put the text right in your question, formatted with the `{}` toolbar button.  Do the same for any output or error messages you wish to add to your question as well.

Comment: The error message is telling you that `feature.darkColor` is neither a `Brush` nor a `Color`, as the two overloads of the `Modifier.background` function accept one of these types as their first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

you are same problem with me

1. you should check Data Class (Feature)
2. `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color` not `android.graphics.Color`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your feature color is either `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color` or `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush`. Also you can use it as

```
Modifier
.padding(7.5.dp)
.aspectRatio(1f)
.background(
   color = feature.darkColor, 
   shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
)
```

without clip

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? You should either supply a Color or Brush from compose library as argument for `Modifier.background`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error message when setting the font Size value to dp instead of sp. Sometimes it gets overlooked.